# Python Idle 3.2 tab glitch

Tags: python, python-idle, python-3.2

In IDLE using 3.2, whenever I enter a statement in a block and press Enter, the cursor jumps ahead. A LOT. It isn't a big deal, but it's annoying. Does it have to do with my code? Is there a fix?

http://www.mediafire.com/view/?kgcg35grt3tllcg

Comment: It is a big deal. The program will not run if you have that issue.

Comment: I was unaware of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I SEE THE PROBLEM! 
Here:

```
def getSystem():
if os.path.exists("C:\"):
    system = "Windows"
```

If you look at the highlighting, the `("C:\")` does not work. I recommend trying to make it `("C:\\")` instead and seeing if that will work. 
I have this problem a lot when I forget a `)`, like if I say `for i in range(len(myList)`, I forgot to put the last `)`. Whenever this happens, just know that there is are unclosed parenthesis somewhere.

Comment: Actually, I looked closer at the code, and instead of doing `("C:\")` as you thought you are, the second " is not a quote. It is some other character which is not a quote, but looks like it. Try replacing that quote with a correct one and see if that works

Comment: Both of us? I'm the only one here

Comment: Oops. I really have to start looking at names.